# NumPy: Fastest way to generate random subset that includes particular element

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to generate a random `k`-subset of `n`-set but with the requirement that element with index `i` is in this subset. Essentially, this:

```
import numpy as np

n = 7
k = 4
i = 2

subset = np.random.choice(n, k, replace=False)
while i not in subset:
    subset = np.random.choice(n, k, replace=False)
print(subset)
```

But perhaps there is a faster way to do that? The values of `n` and `k` are rather small (like 10 or 20) but I need to do this kind of sampling many times for different values, so it would be nice to have something that is fast.

Comment: Does the order of the elements in the random subset need to be random as well?

Comment: Well, if not, it can be fixes by `np.random.shuffle`

Comment: In what way is this different from generating a `k-1`-subset from an `n-1`-set (without restrictions) and then adding element `i` back in?

Comment: it's not - I am just looking for something faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Well the problem is such that `i` has to be there and rest must be random, but uniformly distributed. So, we can use `np.random.choice` with `replace=False` on the rest and append with `i`, Then, randomize it and that's our output. Also, no iterations needed.

Hence, it would be -

```
def create_rand_ar(n,k,i):
    sel_ar = np.r_[:i,i+1:n]
    sel_ar_incl_i = np.r_[i,np.random.choice(sel_ar, k-1, replace=False)]
    np.random.shuffle(sel_ar_incl_i) # skip if order does not matter
    return sel_ar_incl_i
```

To verify that we have `i` always there and rest have equal probabilities to be in the output, here's a run on a large number of iterations and checking the count of occurrences, which should be uniform -

```
In [84]: n = 7
    ...: k = 4
    ...: i = 2

In [85]: outputs = np.array([create_rand_ar(n,k,i) for _ in range(10000)])

In [87]: np.bincount(outputs.ravel())
Out[87]: array([ 5023,  5061, 10000,  4992,  4902,  5006,  5016])
```

**Approach #2**

Another way would be to create a uniform random array in `[0,1)`, set the i-th element to be something `< 0`. Then, do an efficient `argparititon` and select first `k` elements, which guarantees the inclusion of `i` and that's our output. Hence, it would be -

```
def create_rand_ar_v2(n,k,i):
    r = np.random.rand(n)
    r[i] = -1
    return r.argpartition(k)[:k]
```

Verify distribution -

```
In [168]: outputs = np.array([create_rand_ar_v2(n,k,i) for _ in range(10000)])

In [169]: np.bincount(outputs.ravel())
Out[169]: array([ 4946,  5055, 10000,  5071,  4972,  5038,  4918])
```

Timings -

```
In [165]: n = 7
     ...: k = 4
     ...: i = 2

In [166]: %timeit create_rand_ar(n,k,i)
10000 loops, best of 3: 107 µs per loop

In [167]: %timeit create_rand_ar_v2(n,k,i)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.27 µs per loop
```

Comment: Note approach 2 gives a random subset, but the *order* of that subset it not quite random.

Comment: @Ben Yeah, it's inherently because of the way argpartition works that the order is not totally random and also because are adding in `i` as the lowest element. So, we could add an extra layer of `np.random.shuffle()` there if the order is to be kept random too.

Comment: it makes version 2 15 times slower but it's still faster

Answer (score 0):

Nice question, a random choice that always contains one of a value, i.
One way is to remove i, then shuffle, then replace i, thus ensuring it is always there, but never more than once. I make an assumption that your n-set is some other data that can be indexed:

```python
i = 3
k = 7
n = len(data)

idx = list(range(n))
idx.remove(i)
idx = np.append(np.random.choice(idx, k - 1, replace=False), i)
subset = data[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the fastest, but I like to think a contender for the most elegant:

```
subset = np.random.choice(n, k, replace=False)
ipos = np.random.randint(k)
subset = (subset + (i - subset[ipos])) % n
subset
# array([0, 6, 4, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but how about this?

```
elems = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
guaranteed = 'c'
unguaranteed = elems[elems != guaranteed]

temp = np.random.randn(10, len(unguaranteed))  # 10 random subsets
temp = np.argsort(temp)[:, :k]

result = unguaranteed[temp]
result[np.arange(result.shape[0]), np.random.randint(low = 0, high = k, size = result.shape[0])] = guaranteed
```

Comment: Hmm.... But is it going to be faster than the original ("generate until `i` is in the subset") approach?..

Comment: About how many samples do you need? 10, 100, 1000, 1M? That's kind of an important variable for running some timings.

Comment: Between 10K and 100K